# How to run a regression which report all factor variables?

Tags: statistics, regression, stata, categorical-data, economics

I want to run a `regression` that calculates the estimated values for all levels of a `factor` variable. By default, Stata omits one dummy as a `base` level.

When I use the `allbaselevels` option, it just shows a zero value for a `base` level:

```
regress adjusted_volume i.rounded_time, allbaselevels
```

SAS shows all the estimated values of categorical variables when the constant has been removed.

How can i do the same thing in Stata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `allbaselevels` is one of several *display options*, which can be useful when reporting results from estimation commands such as `regress`. But specifying it as an option does not make any difference in the calculations.

As the Stata [manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u25.pdf) points out:

> *"...The allbaselevels option  is much like baselevels,  except allbaselevels lists  base levels  in  interactions  as  well  as  in  main effects.  Specifying
>   allbaselevels will make the output easier to understand..."*

What you are actually looking for is the [`ibn.`](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/u11.pdf#u11.4.3.2) factor-variable operator:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. regress mpg ibn.rep78
note: 5.rep78 omitted because of collinearity

  Source |       SS           df       MS          Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 64)        =      4.91
   Model |  549.415777         4  137.353944       Prob > F        =    0.0016
Residual |  1790.78712        64  27.9810488       R-squared       =    0.2348
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1869
   Total |   2340.2029        68  34.4147485       Root MSE        =    5.2897

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   rep78 |
      1  |  -6.363636   4.066234    -1.56   0.123    -14.48687    1.759599
      2  |  -8.238636   2.457918    -3.35   0.001    -13.14889    -3.32838
      3  |  -7.930303    1.86452    -4.25   0.000    -11.65511   -4.205497
      4  |   -5.69697    2.02441    -2.81   0.006    -9.741193   -1.652747
      5  |          0  (omitted)
         |
   _cons |   27.36364   1.594908    17.16   0.000     24.17744    30.54983
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Of course, you also need to specify the `noconstant` option:

```
. regress mpg ibn.rep78, noconstant

  Source |       SS           df       MS          Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(5, 64)        =    227.47
   Model |  31824.2129         5  6364.84258       Prob > F        =    0.0000
Residual |  1790.78712        64  27.9810488       R-squared       =    0.9467
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.9426
   Total |       33615        69  487.173913       Root MSE        =    5.2897

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   rep78 |
      1  |         21   3.740391     5.61   0.000     13.52771    28.47229
      2  |     19.125   1.870195    10.23   0.000     15.38886    22.86114
      3  |   19.43333   .9657648    20.12   0.000       17.504    21.36267
      4  |   21.66667   1.246797    17.38   0.000      19.1759    24.15743
      5  |   27.36364   1.594908    17.16   0.000     24.17744    30.54983
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer. What about using robust regression? Because `rreg` hasn't `noconstant` option.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all commands support all options. If `noconstant` is not supported by `rreg`, then you can't do it. Why don't you use the `vce(robust)` option in `regress`?